# RSpec - trying to stub a method that returns its own argument

Tags: ruby, rspec, stubbing

I have a method which I'm trying to stub out in my unit test. The real method gets called with one argument (a string) and then sends out a text message. I need to stub out the method but return the string that gets passed in as an argument.

The code I have in my RSpec test is this:

```
allow(taxi_driver).to receive(:send_text).with(:string).and_return(string)
```

This returns:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'string'
```

If I change the return argument to `:string`, I get the following error:

```
Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well
```

I've tried googling and checking the relishapp.com site, but can't find the answer to something which appears quite simple and straightforward.

Comment: How is `send_text` being called? The cause of the error is exactly what it says: You haven't defined `string` anywhere. The argument you give to `with` should be the actual value you expect the method to receive (which I doubt is the symbol `:string`) and the argument you give to `and_return` should be the actual value you want to stub to return, e.g. `allow(taxi_driver).to receive(:send_text).with("I'm the input text").and_return("I'm the output text")`.

Comment: My method is being called like this: ```send_text("the time now is #{Time.now}")```. The string varies according to the time, thats why I need the mock to return the varying string. Perhaps its not within the scope of a mock to do this?

Comment: Actually, I just followed the advice in your edit, I managed to get it working now. Just that it looks really ugly (the strings I used are much longer than my example), I'll look into assigning them to a variable, just really tired after coding for many hours now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a block:

```
allow(taxi_driver).to receive(:send_text).with(kind_of(String)){|string| string }
expect(taxi_driver.send_text("123")).to eq("123")
```

Answer (score 0):

> My method is being called like this: send_text("the time now is #{Time.now}"). The string varies according to the time, thats why I need the mock to return the varying string. Perhaps its not within the scope of a mock to do this?

In such a case, I usually use [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem in order to freeze system time. Here is a sample use case:

```
describe "#send_text" do
  let(:taxi_driver) { TaxiDriver.new }

  before do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2016, 1, 30, 12, 0, 0))
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  example do
    expect(taxi_driver.send_text("the time now is #{Time.now}")).to eq \
      "the time now is 2016-01-30 12:00:00 +0900"
  end
end
```